# Error message if data does not exist while filtering

Tags: vba, excel

My macro below will filter out data starting with
`PB*`

However if the data `PB*` does not exist, I would like a message box to pop up and stop the macro completely.

I hope someone would be able to enhance the macro by adding an "If- Else" statement in it with the message 
`Data does not exist.`

This is the macro I am currently using ...

```
Sub LHEQP()
'
' LHEQP Macro
'

'

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=PB**" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend amending some options to the `Range.Find` method to suit your needs. Available options, and other useful info, can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find)

```
Dim Found as Range
Set Found = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N:N").Find("PB*")

If Found is Nothing Then
    Msgbox "Data does not exist"
Else
    Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=PB*", Operator:=xlAnd
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the visible data in column N with the worksheet's SubTotal function.

```
Sub LHEQP()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    with ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        with .Range("A1:P" & LastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=PB*"
            if not cbool(application.subtotal(103, .columns(14).offset(1,0))) then
               'zero visible data in filtered column N
                msgbox "bad filter"
                exit sub
            end if
        end with

    end with

End Sub
```